# How to initiate a document download from a custom action javaScript without redirecting the page?

Tags: javascript, jsom, custom-actions, download

I want to initiate a download of a pdf file stored in a document library from a custom action ribbon button in another list. The file which to download depends on the current user so it is not just a static link. I got the library item which contains the pdf using jsom.
The download shall start immediately without affecting the main sharepoint page, redirects are not acceptable.
How is it possible to initiate a download from JavaScript within an asynchronous custom action? Is it possible at all?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Can you share the jsom code you have used to get the item ?

Comment: Technically I could, but I'm not allowed to, due to legal restrictions. But its just retreiving a list item based on a query.

Comment: Haven't tried it, what happens when you open the URI an IFRAME

Comment: Thanks! Iframe does the trick:
 $("body").append("<iframe src='" + url + "' />");